# How to import file in Python with changed entry point (sys.path)?

Tags: python, import, relative-path, sys.path, relative-import

I have this structure:

```
web/   
   api/
       app.py
       sets.json
   tests/
        test.py
```

app.py:

```
def func():
    with open('sets.json', 'r') as file:
        ...
```

test.py:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+'/api/')

from app import func
...
```

I want to run tests from the root (web/). Import is successful. But when func are called, I get error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sets.json'`.

Why? Sys.path was changed and import is worked. Why I can't import sets.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, I have got such solution:
I create `tests/conftest.py` (for Pytest, it allows to apply my changes for all files) with code:

```
import sys
import os
os.chdir(os.getcwd()+'/api/')
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

With this solution I can do imports and from `web/api/` (in Docker) and from `web/` (in PyTest) and get access to `sets.json` in `web/api/`.

Answer (score 2):

Because your current working directory is not the same thing as your path, and you used a relative path (`open("sets.json")` == `open("./sets.json")`) so python is looking for `sets.json` in your top level directory, not inside `api`.

Messing around with `sys.path` is not a robust solution to importing anyhow.  I'm not quite sure what is in your `test.py` but you might be better off with a proper test runner (which depending on how you set it up may fix the issue), or you may want to turn your app into a *package* and install it in 'development mode', so that `app` can be found with juggling path.

In any case you want a more robust solution for finding your data, such as using the package path (if you will distribute data with the package), or a particular path like `~/.cache/my-app/my-data`.

Several of the popular web frameworks have support for resolving paths to deployed resources in a package built in, which might be what you're looking for (but you haven't said if you're using one).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/api/` to your `sys.path` doesn't change your current working directory, so in order to access `sets.json` you'll have to modify your code:

```py
def func():
    with open('/api/sets.json', 'r') as file:
        ...
```

Alternatively, a more robust solution involves using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to make your function aware of where it's being ran from by checking the last part of the path and updating the location of your .json file accordingly:

```py
from pathlib import Path
def func():
    if Path.cwd().parts[-1] == 'api':
        set_location = 'sets.json'
    elif Path.cwd().parts[-1] == 'web':
        set_location = 'api/sets.json'
    with open(set_location, 'r') as file:
        ...
```

Comment: N.B. this will fail if `api.py` is called from with `/api`.  But depending on the OP's usecase this might indeed be sufficient.

Comment: @vtasca This option is wrong for me, because I also have Docker, which run app.py from the api/ file, not from the root. So, is there way to change my current directory in the code?

Comment: @PolozAlexey Yes, you could change it with `os.chdir(path)` but a more robust approach would be to make your function aware of where it's being ran from and adjust file paths accordingly - I've modified the answer to account for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of running your tests would be to run them from web dir (which hopefully contains no python files directly) as:

```
$ python -m tests.test # note no py
```

You should remove all your sys.path hacks and rewrite relative paths - never use chdir, this can lead to very subtle bugs in the import system including but not limited to double importing modules in different namespaces - below would do:

```
sets_json = os.path.join(os.path.dirnname(__file__), 'sets.json')
def func():
    with open(sets_json, 'r') as ins:
        ... # do not name your variable 'file', shadows a builtin
```