# Easy way to import functions from another folder , but to work with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am looking for a easy way to import functions from another folder:

```
|--mylib
|   |--__init__.py
|   |--mylib2.py
|
|--mytest
|   |--other.py
|   |--test_one.py
|
|--mymain.py
```

mylib2.py

```
def suma(a,b):
    return a+b
```

mymain.py

```
from mylib.mylib2 import suma
def main():
    a=3
    b=4
    c=suma(a,b)
    print(c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

other.py

```
from mylib.mylib2 import suma

c=suma(1,2)
print(c)
```

test_one.py

```
from mylib.mylib2 import suma

def test_nothing():
    assert True

def test_crash():
    e=0
    #d=30/e
    assert True
```

For some reason I can not call suma from other.py normally (because I don't know how to properly include mylib2.py in a file from mytest folder but following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536794/4451521) I could do

```
python3 -m mytest.other
3
```

The problem is that I don't how to run the pytest including the library

if I do pytest I got a message

```
    from mylib.mylib2 import suma
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

How can I run the test in a simple way?

Comment: How about simply appending the __sys.path__? `import sys; sys.path.append('../mylib')` on `other.py`

Comment: @JihoChoi In my experience, messing around with `sys.path` can lead to lots of issues, especially when you're cooperating with team members. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69300985/how-to-import-file-in-python-with-changed-entry-point-sys-path

Comment: @hide1nbush My thoughts exactly. Unfortunately my code is part of a much bigger code with many members. I don't want to mess with `sys.path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You should also add `__init__.py` inside `mytest` folder.

**Explanation:**

It's easy to misunderstand the concepts between `module` and `package`. I'm still not sure that I have fully understanding them even after years programming on Python. Plz correct me if I'm wrong.

1. If `mytest` folder don't have `__init__.py`, the interpreter will consider `mylib` as a package, similar to `numpy`, `pandas`, when executing  the `pytest` command. The searching process is based on your `PYTHONPATH`. However, you didn't technically install `mylib` package, so the interpreter will raise error like:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'`.
2. By adding `__init__.py`, pytest will consider `mylib` and `mytest` are as normal modules, so you can import `mylib.mylib2` as usual.

**Further reading:**

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)

[Pytest: how to work around missing __init__.py in the tests folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796370/pytest-how-to-work-around-missing-init-py-in-the-tests-folder)

Comment: WOW! this worked and I don't know why or how, so I am looking forward to your explanation. Thousand thanks!

Comment: The funny thing is that pytest works now. but still `other.py` has to be called as `python3 -m mytest.other`, because otherwise it will say "no module named 'mylib'

Comment: @KansaiRobot yup. if you add `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` before `from mylib.mylib2 import suma`, you can see that the `PATH` doesn't include `mylib` when running `python3 -m other` inside `mytest` folder. You can either 1. run `python3 -m mytest.other` under root folder, or 2. using relatively import, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3